# Unity iOS devices audio broken after watching IronSource RewardedAds

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, audio, ironsource

I mute the game audio before the adverts and turn it back on when the adverts are over.

There is no problem on Android.
But after watching adverts on Ios, the sounds stuttering, echo, in short, weird. This does not happen every time, sometimes on the 1st time, sometimes on the 5th time. I also use the IronSource.Agent.SetPauseGame(true); method. In addition, on some ios devices, the AudioSettings.Reset(config) method fixes the sounds, but this did not work on a different ios device. It's a very strange problem and I can't understand why. Does anyone have an idea?

What I have tried

1. IronSource.Agent.SetPauseGame();
2. AudioListener.pause
3. AudioSettings.Reset(config)
4. Switching the sound on and off with Mixer
5. Creating new AudioSource after adverts